# How can i mount hard disk partition without deleting files?

Tags: mount, ntfs

I got this error, when I tried to open my partition ...

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/gr3ch/28DA3B12DA3ADC2E: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda1" "/media/gr3ch/28DA3B12DA3ADC2E"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

In this partition I didn't have windows , I have installed Ubuntu where I have Windows 8 after installation Linux I can't open partition .

Comment: Please rephrase the last paragraph, as it is now is not intelligible...

Comment: This answers all your questions and has solutions for your problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @Rinzwind how can I copy all the files if I can't open it ?

Comment: I have deleted windows ... In local disk C I have installed windows 8 and in this partition I have Linux now . Also I had local disk D and after installation Ubuntu I can't open it . I think that some files(hiberfiles) had been installed in local disk D by windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give an answer, which can be understood by a newbie.

This problem happened because Windows had not been shut down properly before you removed it completely, if I am correct.

You can mount this partition as read-only. Run in terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /media/NTFS-disk
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /media/NTFS-disk
```

Now you can copy all your files from that partition. You can find it in /media/NTFS-disk folder.

After that it makes sense to consider formatting that partition to linux format, like ext4.

This problem can be solved another way by booting from Windows installation media and fixing the partition state using command line. But I do not know exactly how to do it.

Comment: ah you are correct.

Comment: Is it possible to mount file system with rw and without file deletion ? Means we can't delete the files but we can added , edit and read.

Comment: No, it is not possible.